# Layered Navigation: 404 Error when browsing via certain filter

Tags: category, url-rewrite, layered-navigation

We have an issue that occurs when filtering by layered navigation. It's 3rd party. The issue is (at least at our end) very easy to reproduce.

Our catalog structure is pretty simple, having two major categories defined in admin back-end:

- **Men** (`website.com/browse-men-products`) - shown inside mega menu
- **Women** (`website.com/browse-women-products`) - shown inside mega menu too
  [image: Category Structure]

These Product Categories are listed in our layered navigation as 'Filter by Category', which looks like this:

[image: Category Filter]

[image: Brand Filter]

Clicking on any category (i.e. Watches) filters just fine.

But when trying filter more by Brand, it throws a 404 not found error. Note that filtering the other way around, like brand first (Aigner) and then category (Watches) works perfectly.

We noticed that this issue happens only when clicking brand after category via layered navigation. Its respective 404 link looks like:

```
website.com/browse-women-products/watches/filter/brands/aigner/cat/aigner-for-women.html
```

The corresponding successfully working link is:

```
website.com/browse-women-products/filter/brands/aigner/cat/watches-for-women.html
```

Additional Note:

Use Web Server Rewrites: No
Index was performed recently.

We thought we'd look into the 3rd party layered navigation (which lost its support because they shut down business), but we don't want to yet.

Thank you for any hint

Comment: We switched back to rwd template and it seems working fine. So seems the theme (intenso) has some flaws when rendering the brand filter URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that there is indeed a conflict with the theme used (intenso). 
The answer is short, and hopefully a help to those who stumble upon a similar issue.

In the "Layered Navigation" Settings (Configuration > Intenso Theme) there is a default value set for "Routing Suffix" which we must remove. So instead of having default value 'filter', we simply keep it empty. Works like a charm.

[image]